# Amendments to code to copy range as picture

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a code which works perfectly when copying the value of one single cell into a bookmark in a saved word document. I am looking to amend this code so that I can copy a range of cells and paste it as a picture to a bookmark in the word document.

```
Dim objWord As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    objWord.Visible = True

    objWord.Documents.Open "C:\Users\Christopher.Ellis\Desktop\VBA Testing\CPA Test\Master\CE1.docx" ' change as required

    With objWord.ActiveDocument
        .Range.Text = ws.Range("B2:G23").CopyPicture
        .Range.Bookmarks.Item("ContactWOP1").Range.Paste Type:=wdChartPicture

    End With

    Set objWord = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: hi. u just need  to put inside the With objWord.ActiveDocument  this .Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture. but dont forget to make the copy first. to make the copy u can do ws.Range("a1:c4").Copy (change the range to what u need).

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have made changes and it does work - however rather than pasting to the bookmark in the word document it pastes to the top of the word document, over any pre-existing text that was already in the document.

Comment: Any ideas at all @LuisCurado?

Comment: try to replace     Range("a1:c4").Copy to  Range("a1:c4").CopyPicture and make the paste with  .Range.Bookmarks.Item("ContactWOP1").Range.Paste

Comment: Hi @LuisCurado. I have edited my code at the top - should it look like that with your amendments?

Comment: hi, no, inside the with u have to put ws.Range("B2:G23").CopyPicture (this copies to clipboard) and .Range.Bookmarks.Item("ContactWOP1").Range.Paste (paste from clipboard).

Answer (score 0):

With Word, similar to Excel, it's important to use *objects*. So the code below declares and instantiates and object for the target `Word.Document` as well as the target (bookmark) `Word.Range`.

Using a `Document` object, the document being opened can be set directly to the object, making it unnecessary to rely on the uncertain `ActiveDocument` property. With a `Range` object, it's possible to pick up that target position again, if required.

The `CopyPicture` method should be used in Excel when copying the chart if it should be a static graphic in the Word document (rather than a Chart object). This puts the graphic on the Windows Clipboard so that it can be pasted into the document. (It's not possible to assign what you're copying to `Range.Text` in Word BTW.)

```
Dim objWord As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim doc as Object, rng as Object

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    objWord.Visible = True
    Set doc = objWord.Documents.Open "C:\Users\Christopher.Ellis\Desktop\VBA Testing\CPA Test\Master\CE1.docx" ' change as required

    With doc
        ws.Range("B2:G23").CopyPicture
        '.Range.Text = ws.Range("B2:G23").CopyPicture
        Set rng = .Range.Bookmarks.Item("ContactWOP1").Range
        rng.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture
    End With

    Set objWord = Nothing
End Sub
```